# How to represent web pages in OOP

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, web

Let's say there's a web page: shop.com
Basic structure:
`shop.com/search`
`shop.com/user`

`shop.com/user/cart/` needs authentication session.

I am building a parser for this web page using Jsoup, to extract piece of text from a target page. I would like to program it as a "web page as an API".
So my queston is, how should I design my program?

Right now I have something like this:
`Shop shop = new Shop(username, login) // instantiating the user session`
`Document shoppingCart = shop.getShoppingCart(); // returns org.jsoup.nodes.Document`

The problem here is that what if I need more data from many different pages, e.x.:
`shop.findBestDeals() // would not need login session`
`shop.getUsedSearchTerms() // would need login session`
All the parsing weight would be on Shop class. Plus logging the user in for no reason, if page doesn't need it.
So I thought of using static methods like this, where each page would be a class:
`Document cart = Cart.getShoppingCart(usersession)`
`Document deals = Shop.findBestDeals()`
`Document dealsForUser = Shop.findBestDeals(usersession) // if web page would display special items for logged in users`

So basically, have web pages as classes, and they would all have static methods for data retrieval. As I now think about it, each "page-class" would require lots of (the same) imports (as other classes), would it be okay, or is there a design pattern to prevent this from happening?
This is the best I can come up with as a first year student for "web page as an API" problem.
English is not my first language, so feel free to ask further questions! :)

**PS: not a homework, my personal project!**

**EDIT:** Another example: Youtube.com (any video hosting site will do :)) 
I want to be able to programmatically get the list of my private videos.
So I would establish a connection to youtube.com, POST request to log in, and save the session.

Then, do the request, with that login session, to a user_videos.php file and get the html page. 
Then I parse the page, so I get the list of video titles.

That would be one "task", getting titles of my videos. I want to have many tasks. Another one would be to get the list of my friends, for example.
Ultimate goal would be to use that program in another program as a programmatic way of accessing a web page for data extraction without writing scraping code and connections ones self. Think of an API for a web page ("limited edition").

Comment: Have you heard of MVC? You can read more about here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127624/what-is-mvc-really

Comment: *and they would all have static methods for data retrieval* what.... **ONLY** use static for singular items, and even then try to avoid them... Don't do static m'kay? static is bad m'kay(unless you are experienced and you know what static actually does and what the pitfalls and gotcha's are)

Comment: It's good that you're aware of the dangers of having too many responsibilities in a class. Static methods are the antithesis of OOP, they don't work with polymorphism, so avoid them if you can. But I'm not sure that OOP is that helpful either. Why Java?

Comment: This is probably not the best way to go about OOP and web programming, but you probably know this already, so the big question is... _why?_

Comment: @user2204491, I recommend choosing a MVC framework for the technology you'd like to work with. You won't have to write the framework yourself and you'll get to understand the concepts pretty fast.

Comment: I have heard of the MVC pattern, never used it though. Will check out the link and see if it would help me in any way.
Why Java? It's the language I'm most proficient in...
I want to represent web pages as a "data source". I could then use this program to query those pages within their domain. Like in scraping, you  extract data from a web page. I want to have many points from one domain, to extract data from. Oh god, I made it sound even more complicated than it is...

Comment: So, basically, the web page would be a Model, View would be the representation of the Model, which is generated/ controlled by the Controller? I think I am confused.

Comment: I think the MVC advice was given thinking that you intend to design the web site, not to scrape it. It's not as useful in your case.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yeah, I'm trying hard to imagine how to implement it...

Comment: You mentioned that you are "building a parser", but the rest of you question asks about "how to design a web application" which is an entire field and I don't think it can be answered in SO question-answer.

Comment: Not how to design a website, but how to design my program, that acts as a scraper against one particular web page.</br>
See my updated post, for a example.

Comment: @Bv202 MVC is for implementing the UI. Here we're asked how to drive the UI programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to do something similar, with GUI screens rather than web pages.

Java may not be the best language for this, maybe Python is better, especially for coding the "task" itself rather than the pages.

I had a class representing a particular screen. The class would have getters to access the parsed-out contents, "setters" to send the contents on to the screen (implemented via sending keystrokes and mouse clicks) and actions (more clicks). Some actions returned other screens, serving as factory methods.

The entire thing was rather static in the sense that adding another field or action or screen required coding.

Comment: yup, I thought on using a "class per web page (screen, in your case)"  idea also. But how can I design it in an OOP way, so classes are logically structured. Comments suggest I should not use `static`, so I am left with nothing...

Comment: Also, this approach makes me wonder how should I share data (e.x. web page needs information from another page; passing cookies around, etc) between classes?

Comment: The actual pages are instances of the class, so no `static`. Shared data may live in a repository that that is passed to pages on construction.